# How to use OpenVINS Library To Get Position

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, libraries

So, I finally got ROS, OpenCV, and [OpenVINS](https://github.com/rpng/open_vins) installed on my rpi3 running ubuntu 16.04. I want to be able to send the video from a standard rpi monochrome camera setup and mpu-9250 through a VIN application and send the estimated position of the camera over wifi to the game service unity. Ive been looking into their 'getting started' page, and the tutorial seems very high level. Forgive me, for I do not work much with rpi's and more so arduinos, so most of this is new to me. Im trying to understand how I can do this, so far I know i need to send data to some subscribed topics the program is looking under, yet I do not know what data I need to send for each topic, what program I would use to send it, how, and what format it needs to be in. I also dont know if that is the only thing I need to do. And after all this, I still do not understand fully on how to launch the program(s) after everything is fully said and done.

I have read the documentation they have posted over and over and I know they mention the subjects I am mentioning but the sections they talk about that pertain to them in question I cannot fully conceptualize. If someone who has knowledge in the field of using github repositories or uses VINS specifically and would like to make a more low-level tutorial for someone like me that would be much appreciated, if not, do link me to one where I could find descriptors more comprehensive than those provided by this github. The documentation all the while seems great for this repository, and it is a shame I cannot fully utilise it. As always, all input is appreciated, thanks. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may refer to one of the `launch` in [this folder](https://github.com/rpng/open_vins/blob/master/ov_msckf/launch/).
For example, line 24-26 in [this file](https://github.com/rpng/open_vins/blob/master/ov_msckf/launch/pgeneva_ros_tum.launch)

```xml
<param name="topic_imu"      type="string" value="/imu0" />
<param name="topic_camera0"  type="string" value="/cam0/image_raw" />
<param name="topic_camera1"  type="string" value="/cam1/image_raw" />
```

Althrough its a launch file for a rosbag, it indicates that three topics are needed, which are `/imu0`,`/cam0/image_raw`, and `/cam1/image_raw`.
These are the topics you need to provide. If you wish to use monocular VINS, only one camera topic is needed and the param `use_stereo` needs to be set as `false`.

Many other parameters are needed, such as camera intrinsics and extrinsics between camera and IMU.